# Android 12 BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission is granted when denied

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, bluetooth, android-12

So I know Android 12 has new Bluetooth permissions. In the App Info Permissions it looks like its called Nearby Devices now.
I have this logic:

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            viewModel.connectDevice(macAddressDropdown.selectedItem.toString())
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT),
                    1
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

On initial launch, this seems to work fine, it will prompt for the Nearby Device permission as it looks on the Google documentation.
After this, I go into the Permissions in App Info, and I deny the Nearby Devices permission.
When I debug this logic, it is saying BLUETOOTH_CONNECT is still allowed.

```
s = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
a = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
b = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
c = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
d = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission_group.NEARBY_DEVICES) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

When I debug this, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT is the only one showing as true, the rest are false.
Any ideas on why this is happening and how it can be fixed?
Potentially a bug?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing this ! I am seeing the exact same issue . I encountered the same today . Did you find why it is returning as Granted
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69922636/check-if-user-has-granted-access-to-nearby-device-permission

Comment: @luckysing_noobster Good to know somebody else is experiencing it. I haven't found a way to fix it, I am assuming it is a bug or Google has not implemented Nearby Devices as permissions properly yet, since it exists as a permission_group. 
I can confirm when it returns true but is denied in Permissions in App Info, the bluetooth connection doesn't work and returns an error. So I don't really know whats going on

Comment: Just to confirm, this is real, I'm seeing the issue also.

Comment: I updated the target to 31 and it seems to have worked

Comment: @KeithLoughnane just to confirm, api 31 fixes the issue?

Comment: I didn't want to reply before I was finished what I'm working on so I can be 100% sure but for the bluetooth permissions at least it worked.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane so the permission is not granted any more and if you deny the permission in app settings and go into the app again it will ask to reenable it or something?
If its fixed in API 13 you should write it as an answer and I can approve it then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
compileSdkVersion 31
```

changing the target version to 31 fix it for me

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 31
compileSdkVersion 31
```