# Check if user has granted access to nearby device permission

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-bluetooth, android-12

I am reading the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) for the Android Nearby Permission specially for Android 12. I want to check if the user has granted access to Nearby device permission programmatically. The following check is returning true for me all the time

```
 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

I manually revoked the nearby permission after granting it once in the app and also confirmed by going to the app settings which says nearby permission is not granted. Is there a way to check for this runtime and show the nearby device permission(system dialog) if not granted

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. Same here, my app targets Android 11. If the user revokes the Nearby Devices permission on an Android 12 phone, my app cannot scan any BLE peripherals even though it is granted the fine location permission (precise accuracy). I would like at least to be able to warn the user in the application UI. All BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, BLUETOOTH_SCAN and BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE permissions return PERMISSION_GRANTED without respect to the setting.

Comment: I updated the target to 31 and it seems to have worked

Comment: Does any one found the answer for 33?

Comment: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlSuJy9SfzvHSxjM9HwOiL4CbEgvcJb-I